# Cursor behavior changed in Android 4.2 staledata

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an app that works fine on all versions of android since 2.1 but has stopped working on android 4.2.

The app holds a reference to a cursor in the Application and closes the cursor in the onTerminate call. The Cursor is only populated once with data from an SQLite DB which is also held open in the application until onTerminate.

The data in the cursor will never change but it is used to populate a viewpager with an array of values overlayed to change the positions of the data in the viewpager.

The error is below:

> 11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):
>   android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed
>   CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to
>   calling this method. 11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):   at
>   android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   com.ololifepty.wildlife.ReorderingCursorWrapper.getString(ReorderingCursorWrapper.java:71)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   com.ololifepty.wildlife.AnimalPageCursorAdapter.instantiateItem(AnimalPageCursorAdapter.java:128)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:321) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:441) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:271)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:369)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$DataSetObserver.onDataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:983)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:119)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   com.ololifepty.wildlife.WildlifeActivity$1.handleMessage(WildlifeActivity.java:156)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   com.ololifepty.wildlife.WildlifeActivity$1.dispatchMessage(WildlifeActivity.java:87)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-19 05:29:20.600:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-19 05:29:20.600:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   11-19 05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 11-19
>   05:29:20.600: E/AndroidRuntime(993):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

It appears that the cursor is closing but I don't know why. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it as debugging is extremely slow with the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29) for `onTerminate`

It is never called in real devices , it is used only on Emulators.

Comment: I don't think that this onTerminate is the problem as the cursor is closing ahead of time rather than not closing.